# Difficulty maintaining paragraph spacing in Flutter HTML rendering

Tags: flutter, dart

We are facing difficulties in maintaining paragraph spacing while rendering HTML content in a Flutter application. We want to display paragraphs with appropriate spacing between them, but we're encountering issues with the layout.

Here is an example of the HTML content we are trying to render:

```
    <p><strong>Place &#8211; </strong>Na een roerige laatste week waarin wederom de noodzaak tot handelen rondom de Rotte Kies heeft de SP voorafgaand aan de raadsvergadering 418 steunbetuigingen overhandigd aan wethouder van economie, arbeidsmarkt, sport en dienstverlening aangeboden.</p>
<p>Maandag 19 juni was de groot nieuws in de regio. In de ochtend was er een melding van een klein brandje in dit verpauperde complex tegenover het oude ziekenhuis. &#8217;s Middags moesten er echter meerdere brandweerkorpsen uit de regio aan te pas komen om een grote uitslaande brand te bestrijden. Zij konden echter niet voorkomen dat een groot deel van het complex is ingestort waardoor het geheel nu een nóg mistroostiger aanblik heeft.</p>
<p>De SP is sinds 20 mei bezig om steunbetuigingen voor hun petitie te verzamelen waarin de partij de gemeente oproept actie te ondernemen tegen de eigenaar van het terrein. In die periode heeft de SP 418 handtekeningen verzameld, zowel online als fysiek tijdens twee marktdagen. Ook SP Jongeren is maandag nog deur-aan-deur geweest om met de mensen in gesprek te gaan.</p>
<p>Voorafgaand aan de raadsvergadering heeft een bestuurslid van de SP, samen met een delegatie vanuit bestuur en kerngroep de petitie symbolisch overhandigd aan verantwoordelijk wethouder. Namens de afdeling en namens de ondertekenaars riep op om actie te ondernemen. Zeker na de grote brand van afgelopen maandag is het wel duidelijk dat de tijd van pappen en nathouden wel klaar is nu en dat de wethouder lering zou moeten trekken uit de honderden adviezen die door de ondertekenaars van de petitie werden voorgedragen.</p>
<p>De SP zal zeker een vinger aan de pols houden en niet schromen opnieuw in actie te komen als er geen oplossing wordt gevonden binnen afzienbare tijd.</p>
```

We have tried rendering the HTML content using the flutter_widget_from_html package, but the spacing between paragraphs is not being preserved. We have also attempted to manually add spacing using SizedBox, but it seems to interfere with the rendering of the paragraphs.

Here is a simplified version of our code:

```
// Code snippet
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html/flutter_widget_from_html.dart';

class ExampleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('HTML Rendering'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            HtmlWidget(
              '<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p><p>Paragraph 3</p>',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also tried it with:

```
Html(
                data:
                    '<div>${content.replaceAll('</p>', '</p><br><br>')}</div>'),
          ],
```

We expected to see each paragraph displayed with proper spacing between them, but they appear to be tightly grouped together. How can we achieve the desired paragraph spacing while rendering HTML content in Flutter?

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your second example seems to use the `flutter_html` package, which should already take care of it for you.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html

```dart
Html(
  data: '<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2<br>Which contains a second line</p><p>Paragraph 3</p>',
),
```

[image]

And if you're not satisfied with the result, you can simply use a custom style to edit the padding in paragraphs:

```dart
Html(
  data: '<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2<br>Which contains a second line</p><p>Paragraph 3</p>',
  style: {
    'p': Style(padding: HtmlPaddings.symmetric(vertical: 20))
  },
),
```

Which you can edit as you wish, of course.

[image]

If you want to instead use the `flutter_widget_from_html`, you should be able to use their `customStylesBuilder` to add a custom padding to the paragraphs (if it indeed isn't included by default).

#### Update

When I run either of the HTML packages with your example HTML data, they both produce a similar result with padding between the paragraphs by default.

Aside from using the `customStylesBuilder` or `style` attribute of the respective packages, you can also include `style` with some extra `padding` inline, straight inside your HTML data. I.e.

```dart
<style padding="10dp" />
```